# OpenCV SurfDescriptorExtractor extracting different points depending on how the application is launched

Tags: windows, opencv, feature-detection, surf

I'm trying to compute a homography matrix to calibrate a camera image with that of a monitor it's pointing at.  We've developed an automatic calibration routine where we:

1. Display an image on the screen
2. Capture an image using the camera
3. Find find matching features in the images

   1. Detect features in both images using SurfFeatureDetector
   2. Get descriptors using SurfDiscriptorExtractor
   3. Find matching features using FlannBasedMatcher
4. Compute a homography matrix using the best matching points

Our OS is Windows 7 Pro, 64 bit, but we're building as a 32-bit app.  We're using OpenCV 2.4.5.

This works fine from my personal account, but only when I run it from my account by double-clicking the executable. When I run it from Visual Studio, or run the same executable from another account, we get a garbage homography matrix.

It seems to be breaking down in step 3.1.  It looks like the application finds different points when run different ways, even though it's the same camera with the same lighting conditions.

Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior?

Comment: I get the same behavior when using SIFT instead of SURF.

Comment: Problem was the camera image would sometimes be flipped.  Flipping the camera image allowed for good calibration, but it's still a mystery _why_ the camera image would be flipped, and why couldn't SURF or SIFT find corresponding points in an image rotated 180 degrees?